# Python - display list of solid colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I have a list of RGB values and I need to plot them as a set of squares, each representing a different solid color. Using `plt.imshow` I get an array with nine colors, instead of three as intended. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rgb_values = np.array([[ 47,  32,  31], [ 14,  10,  12], [119, 122, 141]])
plt.imshow(rgb_values)
```

[image]

Comment: From [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) regarding the input data: "(M, N): an image with scalar data. The values are mapped to colors using normalization and a colormap." and "(M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int)."  Your case is the first one. Wrap the whole thing in another list, and you should be fine. (or use `reshape` on the numpy array to massage it to the right shape).

Comment: Almost right ;) The solution was `plt.imshow([rgb_values])`

Comment: I guess I didn't express myself clearly. I meant `rgb_values = np.array([[[ 47,  32,  31], [ 14,  10,  12], [119, 122, 141]]])` -- same outcome. Or `plt.imshow(rgb_values.reshape(1,3,3))` -- ditto.